# is there a way to get all the chat list names in web.whatsapp.com using selenium with python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Here is a code snippet which only gets me the first 15 names and not more than that,

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
all_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3Dr46']") #the class name is exclusively the name of the contact name and not the last chat time and last chat message.
for i in all_names:
  print(i.text)
driver.close()
```

Comment: You may have to scroll down for each element and the list will grow dynamically in nature

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly wait doesn't wait for all the elements loaded, once at least match found it stops.
Also, if there are a lot of chats in your whatsapp it's better to scroll to element to get it's text.
So, I'd advice your code to be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_3Dr46']")))
time.sleep(3)
all_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3Dr46']")
for i in all_names:
  actions.move_to_element(i).perform()
  print(i.text)
driver.close()
```